# Can I add a delay on clicking a url, then zoom the image without going small again?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've got an image on a page, which is linked to a project page - I've got it set to zoom in and blur on focus which is working really well, but it shrinks back down. Ideally id want it to stay zoomed and blured, then the click fires so the page changes, without the user seeing the image shrink back down.

This is my current code:

```
.project-zoom {
    transition: transform 1s, filter 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.project-zoom:active {
    -ms-transform: scale(10); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(10); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(10);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

So firstly, I need to add a delay so that when I click the image it does the image zoom first.
Then once the image has zoomed, I want it to stay zoomed.

Is it possible?
I'm guessing I'll need to add a delay to the click with js or jquery, although if its possible in css then that would be much better.

Comment: Can you give more detail. Are you saying that .project-zoom is a href link to another url which on click should apply the style and wait for it to complete before navigating away?

Comment: @Moob
I have projects on a page (Its an image, title and read more button). The image has a class of project-zoom on it. it also has a href link to the actual project information. When someone clicks on the image I want it to open and zoom to full screen then as soon as the image is full screen, I want the page to change to the actual project information page.

Comment: Isn't this solved by my solution below? If not, please give a more detailed description of your requirements and what isnt working.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it stay, then you should add `:focus` instead of `:active` on `.project-zoom` class

```
.project-zoom {
    transition: transform 1s, filter 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
    
.project-zoom:focus {
    -ms-transform: scale(10); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: scale(10); /* Safari 3-8 */
    transform: scale(10);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this reply. I've updated the code but now when I click on the image it doesn't zoom at all. it just follows the link to the next page.. Any ideas why this isnt working?

Comment: Could you show me the HTML codes as well so I can understand it better?

Answer (score 0):

As per [Taufik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77482097/1921385) if you want it to stay use `:focus`.

If you also need a delay on following the link you can do this with JS by replacing the link's default behaviour with one which waits for transition to complete:

```js
const projectzoom = document.querySelector(".project-zoom");

projectzoom.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();//dont follow link
  projectzoom.addEventListener("transitionend", ontransitionend);//listen for transition end
});

function ontransitionend(e){
  if(e.propertyName == "transform"){//if our transform has ended (you have two - transform and filter)
    projectzoom.removeEventListener("transitionend", ontransitionend);//remove the listener
    console.log(`Transition has completed. Redirect to ${e.target.href}`);//redirect to follow the link
    //window.location.href=e.target.href;
  }
}
```

```css
.project-zoom {
    transition: transform 1s, filter 1s ease-in-out;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:block;
    padding:20px;
    background:#eee;
}
    
.project-zoom:focus {
    transform: scale(10);
    filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<a href="#somewhere" class="project-zoom">click me</a>
```